# Find a certain word in a string, and then wrap around it

Tags: php, string

I have a big string, with more than 1000 words. What I need, is to find a certain word, and then wrap some words around it into a variable.

```
$in = 'This is a very long sentence, what I need is to find the word "phone" in this sentence, and after that, to wrap some words around it';
```

How do I achieve this:

```
$out = 'find the word "phone" in this sentence';
```

So, as you can see, when I find the word "phone", I want to expand in the left & right of that word.
A real example is, when you make a query on google, bellow the title result, you get some content from the webpage, and the query is bolded.

Comment: How fuzzy is your matching? Exact matching, or with stemming and such normalization? Do you have position data from your search query?

Comment: Please define what a *word* is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is *a* way to do it. I'm not saying this is the best way, but it will work. There is probably a regex way to do it that would be "nicer" or "better".

```
$in = 'This is a very long sentence, what I need is to find the word phone in this sentence, and after that, to wrap some words around it';
$wordToFind = 'phone';
$numWordsToWrap = 3;

$words = preg_split('/\s+/', $in);
if (($pos = array_search($wordToFind, $words)) !== FALSE) {
  $start = ($pos - $numWordsToWrap > 0) ? $pos - $numWordsToWrap : 0;
  $length = (($pos + ($numWordsToWrap + 1) < count($words)) ? $pos + ($numWordsToWrap + 1) : count($words) - 1) - $start;
  $slice = array_slice($words, $start, $length);
  $out = implode(' ', $slice);
  echo $out;
} else echo 'I didn\'t find it';
```

Answer (score 8):

**The Regex Way**

If you want to highlight certain words (search text) in a string do the following.

**PHP code:**

```
 $in = 'This is a very long sentence, what I need is to find the word phone in this sentence, and after that, to wrap some words around it';
 $wordToFind  = 'phone';
 $wrap_before = '<span class="highlight_match">';
 $wrap_after  = '</span>';

 $out = preg_replace("/($wordToFind)/i", "$wrap_before$1$wrap_after", $in);

 // value of $out is now: 
 // This is a very long sentence, what I need is to find the word <span class="highlight_match">phone</span> in this sentence, and after that, to wrap some words around it
```

**CSS CODE**

Since this example is wrapping the matched text with a span class,  here is the obligatory example CSS code

```
 <style type="text/css">
    .highlight_match {
        background-color: yellow;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
 </style>
```

Answer (score 5):

thanks to @DaveRandom i have just bettered the code and re-writing

```
<?php

$in = 'This is a very long sentence, what I need is to find the word phone in this sentence, and after that, to wrap some words around it';
$wordToFind = 'words';
$numWordsToWrap = 3;
echo $in;
echo "<br />";
$words = preg_split('/\s+/', $in);

$found_words    =   preg_grep("/^".$wordToFind.".*/", $words);
$found_pos      =   array_keys($found_words);
if(count($found_pos))
{
    $pos = $found_pos[0];
}

if (isset($pos)) 
{
    $start = ($pos - $numWordsToWrap > 0) ? $pos - $numWordsToWrap : 0;
    $length = (($pos + ($numWordsToWrap + 1) < count($words)) ? $pos + ($numWordsToWrap + 1) : count($words)) - $start;
    $slice = array_slice($words, $start, $length);

    $pre_start  =   ($start > 0) ? "...":"";    

    $post_end   =   ($pos + ($numWordsToWrap + 1) < count($words)) ? "...":"";

    $out = $pre_start.implode(' ', $slice).$post_end;
    echo $out;
} 
else 
    echo 'I didn\'t find it';
?>
```

you all might like to re-use.

And again thanks to DaveRandom

Comment: I'm trying to implement this in my search function. But when `$wordToFind` contains multiple words it doesn't work. Can you help me out?

Comment: split by some parameter like, u can also go for spaces and then loop it out.

Answer (score 3):

This is a relatively simple example of how you could accomplish that:

```
<?php

   $in = "blah blah blah test blah blah blah";
   $search = "test";
   $replace = "--- test ---";

   $out = str_replace($search, $replace, $in);

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$out=preg_match('/\w+\s+\w+\s+\w+\s+\"phone\"\s+\w+\s+\w+\s+\w+/',$in,$m);
if ($out) $out=$m[0];
```

If the quotes are optional and you want dome flexibility concerning special characters use

```
preg_match('/\w+[^\w]+\w+[^\w]+\w+[^\w]+phone[^\w]+\w+[^\w]+\w+[^\w]+\w+/',$in,$m);
```

and if you want to match partial words use

```
preg_match('/\w+[^\w]+\w+[^\w]+\w+[^\w]+\w*hon\w*[^\w]+\w+[^\w]+\w+[^\w]+\w+/',$in,$m);
```

to match "hon" in phone

Comment: `\W == [^\w]` - might make the pattern more readable. Also a note on [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/preg_quote) might be useful.

Comment: @hakre Sorry to be so stupid, but I dont undertand your comment

Comment: You can replace each `[^\w]+` with `\W+`. `preg_quote` can be used to insert the search term ensuring the pattern won't break.

Comment: `[^\w]+` and `\W+`are exact opposites! The first matches **everything but** a wird character (such as blanks or quotes), the second matches the words. This is how I count the 3 words left and right

Comment: No, those two are the same. Mind the case difference between `\w` and `\W`, see as well http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php.

Comment: @hakre Sorry, I didn't notice the case! looked too similar on this display. In this case you are ofcourse right, I personally still prefer the [^\w] for exactly this reason - a quick look over it shows the difference immediately

Answer (score 0):

```
$in = 'This is a very long sentence, what I need is to find the word phone in this     sentence, and after that, to wrap some words around it';

$array = explode(" ", $in);

$how_much = 3;

$search_word = "phone";

foreach ($array as $index => $word) {
    if ($word == $search_word) {
        for ($index1 = 0; $index1 < ($how_much * 2) + 1; $index1++) {
            $key = $index-$how_much+$index1;
            echo $array[$key];
            echo " ";
        }
    }
}
```

This is simple solution. Explode sentence on spaces, and then display your word + $how_much words in both directions.